# How to record v4l webcam with ffmpeg? Cannot find a proper format for codec 'none'

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, avconv, v4l

Goal is to capture video from my old usb webcam (device 0733:0430). Trying to save video gives this error. (I've tried both ffmpeg and avconv.)

Command `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video2 -s 160x120 tmp.mkv`

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x815280] Time per frame unknown
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x815280] Cannot find a proper format for codec 'none' (id 0), pixel format 'none' (id -1)
Assertion *codec_id != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE failed at /build/buildd/ffmpeg-2.3/libavdevice/v4l2.c:802
```

I know it can work on Linux, because I had it running a few years ago. How to get it to work now?

---

**Below is information about the device.**

Device dmesg output

```
[53008.270283] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[53008.363405] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0733, idProduct=0430
[53008.363416] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[53008.779745] gspca_main: v2.14.0 registered
[53008.809496] gspca_main: spca505-2.14.0 probing 0733:0430
[53008.812508] usbcore: registered new interface driver spca505
```

ffmpeg -list_formats 1 -f v4l2 -i /dev/video2

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xbed5e0] Raw       : Unsupported :                 S505 : 160x120 176x144 320x240 352x288
```

v4l-info /dev/video2

```
### v4l2 device info [/dev/video2] ###
general info
    VIDIOC_QUERYCAP
        driver                  : "spca505"
        card                    : "USB Camera (0733:0430)"
        bus_info                : "usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2"
        version                 : 3.13.11
        capabilities            : 0x85000001 [VIDEO_CAPTURE,READWRITE,STREAMING,(null)]

standards

inputs
    VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT(0)
        index                   : 0
        name                    : "spca505"
        type                    : CAMERA
        audioset                : 0
        tuner                   : 0
        std                     : 0x0 []
        status                  : 0x0 []

video capture
    VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT(0,VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        index                   : 0
        type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
        flags                   : 0
        description             : "S505"
        pixelformat             : 0x35303553 [S505]
    VIDIOC_G_FMT(VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
        fmt.pix.width           : 160
        fmt.pix.height          : 120
        fmt.pix.pixelformat     : 0x35303553 [S505]
        fmt.pix.field           : NONE
        fmt.pix.bytesperline    : 160
        fmt.pix.sizeimage       : 28800
        fmt.pix.colorspace      : SRGB
        fmt.pix.priv            : 0

controls
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+0)
        id                      : 9963776
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "Brightness"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 255
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 127
        flags                   : 32
```

Comment: It took about 15 minutes to check all combinations of pix_fmt and framerate. They all appear to have resulted in the same error. I used this to check - `ffmpeg -pix_fmts | sed 1,8d | awk '{ print $2; }' | while read i; do for j in $(seq 60); do ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video2 -pix_fmt "$i" -r "$j" -s 160x120 -y tmp.mkv; echo "$i $j"; done; done`

Comment: Clever stuff. The "same error" being the original error?

Comment: Same as original error, yes

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [guvcview](https://guvcview.sourceforge.net/). That's how I got my old webcam (Creative model CT6840) to work.

Though, I still couldn't get it to work with ffmpeg and ffplay. I hope someone can help us out here...

Comment: Since OP explicitly mentioned the need to *work with ffmpeg* I am afraid this answer does not bring much more than declaring… "I'm facing that problem too…" ;-)

Comment: I understand, though having an alternative while getting ffmpeg to work is a good thing. I am sure people looking for an answer (like me) can use guvcview to atleast check that their camera does output a video and it is only a matter of getting ffmpeg to work. I think this information is quite helpful :)